# Reading different amounts of inputs in one line

Tags: c, input

I am trying to write a program (in C) in which a user is asked for input, and either inputs 1 input on a line or 2 inputs on the same line depending on what they want to do. My code looks like this:

```
int cmd_type, cmd_input;
printf("Enter command:/n")
scanf("%d %d", &cmd_type, &cmd_input);
```

Some of the commands I am planning to do may have a required input for **cmd_input**, however some of them may just need the user to enter something for **cmd_type**, and **cmd_input** does not need anything. Whenever I run my code, the code works fine if they enter something for **cmd_input**, but if they do not, the code stops and waits for another input.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You will simply have to do two separate `scanf()` calls: first read `cmd_type`, then check it, and you can decide whether you need to do another `scanf()` for `cmd_input` or not...

Comment: If you want to read a line of input and then parse it, why not write code to read a line of input and then parse it?

Comment: First, you should stop using `scanf`.  If you want to ignore that advice, then check the return value from `scanf`.  It will be far more difficult to use `scanf` for this, since many format specifiers treat all white space the same so you can't tell the difference between a space and a newline, but if you want to try to do things the hard way, it can be done. But not with `"%d %d"`

Comment: Lamentix, what should happen if input is neither 1 or 2 `int` inputs?